# Java - simple way to have the program create doubles

Tags: java, integer, double

The input of the program contains n amount of doubles.
I want each double stored as: `a(n), where n = n++`

like this:

```
input 6,57  4,56 1,23
```

should be stored as:

```
a(0) = 6,57
a(1) = 4,56
a(2) = 1,23
etc.
```

This is what i've tried to do:

```
double a;
int n = 0;

scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
a(n) = scanner.nextDouble();

while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
  a(n) = scanner.nextDouble();
  n++;
  break;
}
```

This does not work out,
any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't know about size inadvance ,So I suggest to use `List<Double>` instead of array.
2. You have number in local format (seperated by `,`) so use `NumberFormat` class to get the java format.
3. Numbers are separated with space and are stored in a line in your input,so use `next()` method.
   Try this code.

   ```
   List<Double> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
   scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String number  = scanner.next();
      NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
      a.add(numberFormat.parse(number).doubleValue());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an array. Arrays are fixed size so you must know the number of elements in advance.

Create the array with `double[] a=new double[size]` where `size` is the array size you want.

You can now set the array's values with `a[n]=scanner.nextDouble();`. Remember that `n` will go from `0` to `size-1`. You can read out values this way as well, for example `System.out.println(n[2]);

Comment: But how would you do this when the size of the array is unknown? 
It could e.g. contain 3 doubles, but could contain 100 doubles as well.

Comment: @MartiiJn I suggest a list as the other answer suggests. For learning purposes, however, I advocate getting familiar with arrays first as they will come in handy.